# Saving an Excel Workbook on the Server through ASP.NET and IIS7

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis-7, interop, windows-server-2008-r2

The following code samples produce the same error when I perform the SAVEAS:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
filePath = (string.Format("{0}.{1}", Path.GetTempFileName(), "xls"));
```

...do some stuff to the workbook ...

```
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filePath)
```

OR

```
Missing m = Missing.Value;
excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filePath, m, m,m,m,m, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, m,m,m);
```

OR

```
excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filePath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Here's the error:
Exception: **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.SaveAs(Object Filename, Object FileFormat, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object ReadOnlyRecommended, Object CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode, Object ConflictResolution, Object AddToMru, Object TextCodepage, Object TextVisualLayout, Object Local)
   at Common.CreateTempExcelFile(DataTable data)**

I had the Office 2003 interops on the server but have upgraded to 2007. No difference.

Incidentally, I can write a text file to the same file/path so it's not a permissions error on the folder.

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642527/unhandled-exception-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x800a03ec I found this link useful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like invalid interop version of Excel was installed.